# FAILED Build and run android app using kikapp

Tags: php, android, command-line-interface, ubuntu-16.04

for the first time. I have not modified the code, just run the app through cli and finally get an error like this. can you help me

```
========== Run project started ==========
```

Checking AndroidConfiguration.properties
Checking run requirements
Parallel execution is an incubating feature.
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:main:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:main:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:main:checkDebugManifest
:main:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:main:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2420Library UP-TO-DATE
:main:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72420Library UP-TO-DATE
:main:prepareComAndroidSupportCustomtabs2420Library UP-TO-DATE
:main:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCompat2420Library UP-TO-DATE
:main:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUi2420Library UP-TO-DATE
:main:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUtils2420Library UP-TO-DATE
:main:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportFragment2420Library UP-TO-DATE
:main:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportMediaCompat2420Library UP-TO-DATE
:main:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42420Library UP-TO-DATE
:main:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2420Library UP-TO-DATE
:main:prepareComGenexusFlexibleClient10Library UP-TO-DATE
:main:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase840Library UP-TO-DATE
:main:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement840Library UP-TO-DATE
:main:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm840Library UP-TO-DATE
:main:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation840Library UP-TO-DATE
:main:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps840Library UP-TO-DATE
:main:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMeasurement840Library UP-TO-DATE
:main:prepareComMakeramenRoundedimageview201Library UP-TO-DATE
:main:prepareDebugDependencies
:main:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:main:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:main:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:main:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:main:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:main:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:main:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:main:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:main:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:main:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:main:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:main:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:main:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:main:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
:main:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:main:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:main:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:main:prePackageMarkerForDebug
:main:transformClassesWithDexForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:main:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:main:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:main:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:main:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:main:validateDebugSigning FAILED
jarsigner: unable to open jar file: /home/oimtrust/www/TestingApp/Android/main/build/outputs/apk/main-release-unsigned.apk
error: Unable to open '/home/oimtrust/www/TestingApp/Android/main/build/outputs/apk/main-release-unsigned.apk' as zip archive
Checking device state
Installing apk on device
error: An error occurred running: cd /home/oimtrust/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/ 
 ./adb -d install -r /home/oimtrust/www/TestingApp/Android/main/build/outputs/apk/main.apk
error: adb: error: cannot stat '/home/oimtrust/www/TestingApp/Android/main/build/outputs/apk/main.apk': No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

You did not type the command in the same location as the .apk file

Comment: What does that mean? How did you know that?

Comment: I encountered the same issue moments ago